# Danger from NOT connecting cables

Tags: circuit-design

We have a new LED roof-lamp at our home and I ordered a matching dimmer-switch to replace one switch in a 3-way-switching. To have matching wall-elements, I also ordered a replacement for a normal toggle-switch (for another roof-lamp) and a normal power-outlet in the same "wall-group".

I was able to replace the topmost toggle-switch without any problems, but when I wanted to replace the 3-way-switching switch in the middle with the dimmer, I got stuck because there were four cables instead of three as indicated in the dimmer instructions circuit-diagram. I know when to better stop, so I will not temper around with the installation and let the rest be a job for the electrician.

However, since I turnred off electricity for the room circuit, I wanted to at least connect the old switches again and have everything work as usual in the meantime. I failed (and I honestly don't know where), since the GFCI kicked in.

My question now is: Until an electrician installes everyhing correctly it might take some days or weeks - is it okay to have all cables loose and unconnected (with the ends protected against touching, off course) in the meantime? Or is there any danger from NOT connecting cables? I would like to use the other wall-outlets and lights in the room that are not directly related to this wall-group.

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: As long as they are protected with an insulator, not conduction should occur.  If it gets shorted somehow and a circuit is completed, then it might get dangerous.  It would only depend of the body or object resistance at that point.  And the ground path of course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs in DIY.se the home improvement stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Until an electrician installes everyhing correctly it might take some days or weeks - is it okay to have all cables loose and unconnected (with the ends protected against touching, off course) in the meantime?"

"Or is there any danger from NOT connecting cables?"

At least one of the four wires you describe will be "live" and (literally) have the potential cause injury or death through shock and/or fire. Please make sure that you do indeed insulate each end away from others and anything conductive that may come into the box. Otherwise, as long as the wires are as you describe, they should be electrically safe until the electrician gets there.

One thing, not safety related, household fixture LED's usually come as "dimmable" and "non-dimmable. You may want to double check to make sure this is a dimmable LED, as they use a duty cycle to quickly flash short or long durations to give the appearance of dim or bright light.

Comment: Thank you and all others for the clear and precise answers! I indeed checked that the lamp is dimmable and also double-checked on the type of dimmer that is required.

Answer (score 0):

If they are correctly isolated (using electrical tape, or electrical splice strips), there should be no danger in leaving any wires unconnected.